# Laravel passing data to view

Tags: php, laravel

**This is my blade file**

```
<h1>Reports for {{$site_name}} </h1>
```

**This is my Controller**

```
public function showSpecificSite($site_id, $site_name){

$reports = Report::whereHas('site', function($query) use($site_id) {
    $query->where('site_id', $site_id);
})->get(['email_date', 'url', 'recipient']);

$site_name = Site::find(site_name)->get();

  return view('newsite', compact('site_id', 'site_name', 'reports'));
}
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('sites/{site_id}', 
['as'=>'SpecificSite','uses'=>'ReportController@showSpecificSite']);
```

i'm new in laravel

I have a question about passing data to view.blade

My reports are working well but I want to get the site_name value from the site table as well. Do you have any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: new is fine bro. $site_name is an object. Let's say the column in your database is 'name', ask for `$site_name->name` If you do a `dd($site_name)` you'll see what's inside your object.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I want to do that but my error is this ReportController::showSpecificSite(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected

Comment: Then this is a problem in your route. Please post your route.php pointing to this controller function.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey already edited thanks for waiting.

Comment: Its working now @DimitriMostrey thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands, `Site::find(site_name)->get();` should a fatal error, as `site_name` is not defined as a global or otherwise. To get a single property from a database, use the `pluck()` method:

```php
$siteName = Site::where("id", "=", $site_id)->pluck("site_name");
```

Note: Couldn't make it work with `::find($site_id)`, but might just be an issue with my Model.

Comment: I'am so sure that your code was working but my error is this ReportController::showSpecificSite(), 1 passed and exactly 2 expected 
is it because of my use is only $site_id?

Comment: Well, your function is `showSpecificSite($site_id, $site_name)`, (notice 2 params)? I was gonna make a note of this; to me, it looks like you already have `$site_name`, so trying to define it again in that function doesn't make a lot of sense. But yeah, the error is basically saying only one of `$site_id` and `$site_name` is being passed to that function.

Comment: is it because of my value of `$reports` was only `use($site_id)` ? That's why only one parameters got passed

Comment: In the Route, you can add a second parameter, just add a '?', for instance, `Route::get('/site/{id}/{name?}', ....);` followed by `showSpecificSite($id, $name = null) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this line instead:

```
$site_name = Site::find($site_id)->name;
```

Where *name* is the column where you're saving the site name in your table